# Custom method instead of resource for Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Using 4.2 and trying to add a custom method to my controller.

My routes are:

```
Route::get('ticket/close_ticket/{id}', 'TicketController@close_ticket');
Route::resource('ticket', 'TicketController');
```

Everything CRUD wise works as it should, but at the bottom of my TicketController I have this basic function:

```
public function close_ticket($id) {
    return "saved - closed";
}
```

When I am showing a link to route on my page:

```
{{ link_to_route('ticket/close_ticket/'.$ticket->id, 'Mark As Closed', array($ticket->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```

I constantly get a route not defined error, but it surely is defined...?

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Comment: I would like that to have fixed it, but was a type when putting onto SO. The problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laravel helper method `link_to_route` generates an HTML link. Which mean when clicked, the user will be performing a `GET` request.

In your routes file, you are defining this as a `POST` route.

```
Route::post(...)
```

Also, take a look at the docs for `link_to_route` here:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers

You'll see that the first argument should be *just* the route name, without the ID appended.

Comment: Thought that was also the case but upon testing still no luck. This SHOULD work in my eyes...

Comment: @user2921557 Then update your post. Fix the typo, update the `Route::post`. Show exactly what your current code is now.

Comment: If I directly visit the URL it works fine, I'll do some more digging.

Comment: Super. =) So my answer did in fact fix the route. Now you need to examine the source of your HTML page to see what link `link_to_route` is generating, and why it isn't the same as when you directly visit the url.

Comment: Look at the docs for `link_to_route` here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers. You'll see that the first parameter should _just_ be the route name, without the ID appended.

Comment: :) It appears to be the link to route. I guess im just linking to a URL and not a route itself. Not as nice, but have simply made the link a normal HTML <a> link with the URL I need and it works fine.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer to show how you could use `link_to_route` if you still wanted. Plain HTML though is just fine as well. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

`link_to_route` expects a route name, not a url. This is why you are getting 'route not defined' errors, because you have not defined a route with the name you supplied to `link_to_route`.  If you give your route a name, you can use `link_to_route`.

Given the following route definition, the name of the route is now 'close_ticket':

```
Route::get('ticket/close_ticket/{id}', array('as' => 'close_ticket', 'uses' => 'TicketController@close_ticket'));
```

The value for the 'as' key is the route name. This is the value to use in `link_to_route`:

```
{{ link_to_route('close_ticket', 'Mark As Closed', array($ticket->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
```